# How to restream an HTTP stream over RTSP with VLC?

Tags: ubuntu, video, vlc-media-player, docker, streaming

I want to use VLC 3.0.6 to take in an HTTP stream and restream it over RTSP, basically using it as an RTSP server.
I tried using this command

`cvlc http://0.0.0.0:8080/stream?topic=/iris/camera1/image_raw --rtsp-host 0.0.0.0 --rtsp-port 8554 --sout "#rtp{port=8554,sdp=rtsp://0.0.0.0:8081/test.sdp}"`

and get no errors. But when trying to view the stream with VLC (`vlc rtsp://0.0.0.0:8081/test.sdp`) it doesn't play and `Created new TCP socket 36 for connection` is printed every few seconds. FFplay (`ffplay rtsp://0.0.0.0:8081/test.sdp`) says

`[rtsp @ 0x7f25e4000b80] UDP timeout, retrying with TCP   0B f=0/0

[rtsp @ 0x7f25e4000b80] method PAUSE failed: 405 Client error=0/0

[rtsp @ 0x7f25e4000b80] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: mjpeg, none(bt470bg/unknown/unknown)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options`

I think I'm close but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Also I'm doing this in an Ubuntu 18.04 Docker container.